# ASP.NET PAGE TRACE Results

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, memory, trace

Hi I am testing a .NET website with Trace Enabled and everything seems normal, to me, except one thing:

```
Category    Message      From First(s)      From Last(s)
aspx.page   End Load     4,69992678581181   4,699362
```

This seems like an extraordinarily large number for 'End Load'.

I am clueless as to how to use a Trace result correctly, so my best (educated) guess, is that a large number in 'End Load' is probably a result of poor memory management?

And, if so, what are some basic guidelines for things to avoid, and things to do?

Thank you
-Theo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These numbers have nothing to do with memory management. The give you the number of seconds since some point, i.e:

- **From First (s)**: The elapsed time in seconds since the first trace message was processed. The first trace message appears at the top of the list.
- **From Last (s)**: The elapsed time in seconds between the processing of the current trace message and the preceding trace message.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kthye016%28VS.85%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: I'm just curious what goes on in the 'End Load' part which takes much much longer than anything else, if not EVERYTHING else, in the trace!